# function is getting called before service execution angular 4

Tags: angular, service, observable, subscribe

I have one service call which should be done in order to get an array of object.

But before the service call happens the other function is calling.

Which leads to breaking the code.

Is there any way I can subscribe to service and call the other function only if I get a successful response.

I have tried subscribing the service using return and observable but not got any luck

//main call is happeing here

```
  if (Type === CF) {
     return this.Template(RequestObject,Preference, isProv, tType);
  }
```

//method call which will return the object after modification

```
   private Template(RequestObject: RequestObject, Preference: 
  string,
   isProv: boolean, tType: string): DocumentGenerateRequestObject {
  this.tType = this.dataService.getBenefit();

  // For Prov
  if(isProv){
    this.getDocListId('PROV', this.tType);//expecting array of result this.Element here

    this.Element.forEach((type) => {
           if (Preference === BL) {
             if (type.value ==='BLC') {
               RequestObject.masterListID = type.code;
             }
           } });

  }

  // Non Prov
  this.getDocMasterListId('NON_PROV', this.tType); //expecting array of result this.Element here

    this.Element.forEach((type) => {
   this.getDocMasterListId('NON_PROV', this.tType);
      if (Preference === BL) {
        if (type.value ==='BLC_NON') {
          RequestObject.masterListID = type.code;
        }
      }});
  return RequestObject;
```

}

//service call to get the array

```
public  getDocListId(category,ttype){


  this.mdaService.getdoc(category,ttype.toUpperCase())
   .subscribe((res) => {
     const docArray = [];
     if (res) {
  res.map(item => {
    docArray.push({code:item.Id, value:item.Type});
  });
   }
this.Element = docArray;
console.log(this.Element);
  },
 (error) => {
 }
);
```

}

I am expecting the object should update with masterListID but it is not going to the service call and directly throwing Element of undefined.

Comment: `public  getDocListId(category,ttype){` JavaScript ???

Comment: It’s angular 4 component

Answer (score 0):

I believe the service is making an `HTTP` call which is an `Asynchronous` call. By the time the call gets executed, the HTTP hasn't completed fetching the `docArray`. Try using `async` keyword and `await` for the call to fetch the required data before using the `Element` property.

Comment: Can you provide example for this?